# Cannot reset noUiSlider

Tags: javascript, jquery

hey I have checked topics which are about resetting noUiSlider but I could not find a way to deal with mine. Any suggestions ?

```
<div class="row">
<div class="small-6 columns">
<button type="reset" class="w2-button w2-button-black button-reset">reset</button>
</div>  
<div class="small-6 columns">
<button type="submit" class="w2-button w2-button-black">Update</button>
</div>
</div>

noUiSlider.create($('#productspage-price-slider')[0], {
            start: [productsModel.priceFrom, productsModel.priceTo],
            connect: true,
            range: {
                min: productsModel.minPrice,
                max: productsModel.maxPrice
            },
            format: {
                from: function (value) {
                    return Math.round(value);
                },
                to: function (value) {
                    return Math.round(value);
                }
            },
            tooltips: true
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first save the slider instance into a variable, like this:

```
var slider = noUiSlider.create($('#productspage-price-slider')[0], {
```

then create an event handler for the reset button, and [set](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/slider-read-write/) the inital values

```
$("button[type=reset]").on("click", function(){
    slider.set([productsModel.priceFrom, productsModel.priceTo]);
});
```

See a working example here: [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/sx6dfcaL/3/)